# Spring Boot MeterRegistryCustomizer with NewRelicRegistry not working as I expect.

Tags: spring-boot, newrelic, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I have a bean, set up in a configuration class. My goal is to transform, deny, apply common tags and modify the metrics that are sent to New Relic.

Here is my configuration class

```
@Configuration
@Log4j2
public class MetricsConfig {

    private static final Duration HISTOGRAM_EXPIRY = Duration.ofMinutes(10);
    private static final Duration STEP = Duration.ofSeconds(5);
    private final transient String profile;

    @Autowired
    public MetricsConfig(@Value("${spring.profiles.active}") final String profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }

    @Bean
    public MeterRegistryCustomizer<NewRelicMeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags() {
        log.info("Configuring Registry");
        return registry -> registry.config()
                .commonTags(Arrays.asList(Tag.of("appId", "1111111"), Tag.of("environment", profile),
                        Tag.of("app", "aws-app-name")))
                .meterFilter(new MeterFilter() {
                    @Override
                    public Meter.Id map(Meter.Id id) {
                        if(id.getName().startsWith("http")){
                            return id.withName("app-name." + profile + "." + id.getName());
                        }
                        return id;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public DistributionStatisticConfig configure(Meter.Id id, DistributionStatisticConfig config) {
                        return config.merge(DistributionStatisticConfig.builder()
                                .percentilesHistogram(true)
                                .percentiles(0.5, 0.75, 0.95)
                                .expiry(HISTOGRAM_EXPIRY)
                                .bufferLength((int) (HISTOGRAM_EXPIRY.toMillis() / STEP.toMillis()))
                                .build());
                    }
                }).meterFilter(MeterFilter.deny(id -> {
                    String uri = id.getTag("uri");
                    log.info("id: [{}]", id);
                    return (uri != null && uri.startsWith("/swagger") && uri.startsWith("/manage")) || !id.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith("app-name");
                }))
                ;
    }

}
```

Then, I also inject `MeterRegistry` into some of my classes to capture custom events (Timer, Counter).

Everything works in regards to capturing the events, except that the data in New Relic is missing the commonTags, transformations, and anything else that I apply in `MetricsConfig` class.

Am I missing something on making sure my app is wiring up the  `MeterRegistryCustomizer` correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Arg.. I had implemented a HandlerInterceptorAdapter to attempt to implement a Counter for all requests with additional tags. Which, it did not like.